# PHP: Read specific lines in a large file (without reading it line-by-line)

Tags: php, file-io

I have this file structure:

```
line1 (number or a a short string)
line2 (can be several MB of text)
;
line1
line2
;
line1
line2
;
...
```

The total filesize is exceeding 100MB so reading it line by line each time is rather slow.
I want to read only "line1" of each block and skip all the "line2". Or just read a line which I know the linenumber for. Is there any way that I can do it with php? The standard methods of reading lines takes the lines into memory and it not so effective with this structure.

(I know a database structure would be a much better use but this is a study-case that I really want an solution to.)

Comment: Build an index of line pointers for your file if it's static?

Comment: ^ That. Scan the file (in smallish chunks) for the positions of each newline, then you can go back and scan a few characters at the start of each line much more easily. Preprocessing is your friend.

Comment: How big is your PHP process? You could load it in in 20M chunks, say, and then scan it five times. That'd be much quicker than a line by line approach.

Comment: you could try `SplFileObject`, which could read every 3rd line without loading the other 2

Comment: are you running on windows or linux >?

Comment: I don't understand how to build line pointers. Can somebody give me a working example?
Server is running Linux but i'm not really interested in bash commands.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Using splfileobject

- no need to read all lines 1 by 1
- can "jump" to desired line

In the case you know the line number :

```
//lets say you need line 4
$myLine = 4 ; 
$file = new SplFileObject('bigFile.txt');
//this is zero based so need to subtract 1
$file->seek($myLine-1);
//now print the line
echo $file->current();
```

check out : 
http://www.php.net/manual/en/splfileobject.seek.php

Comment: Excellence! I did some benchmarks and this does the job really nicely.
On a 100MB file it took 0.52μs to find the last line.
Reading line by line took 0.97μs to perform the same task.
The execution time is linear based on the number of lines but splfileobject does the job almost double as fast.