# Reading Specific Lines In Text File With PHP

Tags: php, file-io, seek

I would like to read from lines 51 to 100 in a text file using PHP.

The text file contains less than 500 lines at any given time.

I want to read from lines 51 to 100. No other lines.

I hope you understand the question. I've used SO many times and love it. Just cannot find an answer to this one anywhere.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I googled "read specific text lines using php" and the first 9 returns were SO links. Do any of them solve your problem? You should also look at [ask] to get an idea of how the site works.

Comment: SO isn't a "give me the code" Q&A site. **If you want someone to write your code for you the seek a professional and pay the price!** We try to help with code that isn't working but you need to show what you have tried by posting your existing attempt to solve the problem (**i.e. show us the code**). Again, I refer you to [ask].

Comment: I did not give downvote. :( ... It is that misinterpret its text, but it is not out of spite them. The way you wrote confused, I give you a upvote!

Comment: Once again, I know what I want. I have been able to show show the last 50 lines or the first 50 lines in a text file. I just cannot figure out how to show specific lines. I'd like to show lines 51 to 100.

Comment: But that's exactly what my code attempts to do but to be a bug in it. It is not working as expected? Please do not worry, I'm just trying to help you. I do not answer copied from nowhere, I formulated the example. If it is failing let me know :)

Comment: @enoma9 - The solution provided by Guilherme below works by passing 3 parameters.  `$file` - the file you wish to read ,  `$init` - the starting line number you wish to start reading from (eg 51),  and `$end` - the line you wish to finish reading at (eg 100) .  It returns the contents of all those lines as a string.

Comment: It's not working, the one that Guilherme gave me. I don't know what's wrong. It shows a fatal error.

Comment: It is possible the host you are using is preventing fopen() from working. How are you opening the files currently in your php script.  Could you please edit your post with an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `while`, `fopen` and `feof` (it is good for read big files 8) ), like this:

```
<?php
function retrieveText($file, $init, $end, $sulfix = '')
{
    $i = 1;
    $output = '';

    $handle = fopen($file, 'r');
    while (false === feof($handle) && $i <= $end) {
        $data = fgets($handle);

        if ($i >= $init) {
            $output .= $data . $sulfix;
        }
        $i++;
    }
    fclose($handle);

    return $output;
}
```

Example on how to use this function to get lines 51 to 100 :

```
echo retrieveText('myfile.txt', 51, 100);
```

Add break line:

```
echo retrieveText('myfile.txt', 51, 100, PHP_EOL);
```

Add break line in html:

```
echo retrieveText('myfile.txt', 51, 100, '<br>');
```

Comment: Another example, can be found here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19358539/php-read-specific-lines-in-a-large-file-without-reading-it-line-by-line .  This allows for reading files of any size, and seeking to specific points in the file.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I am unable to figure this out and its driving me insane.

Comment: <?php
function retrieveText($file, $init, $end)
{
    $i = 0;
    $output = '';

    $handle = fopen($file, 'r');
    while (false === foef($handle) && $i <= $end) {
         $i++;
         $data = fgets($handle);
         if ($i >= $init) {
              $output .= $data;
         }
    }
    fclose($handle);

    return $output;
}?>
<?php
echo retrieveText('0jth2.txt', 51, 100);
?>

Comment: I posted the code I used. IT is still showing a fatal error and not working.

Answer (score 3):

Just posting another example here based off Guilherme's example :

After testing Guilherme's code on my box, I found that it was having errors pertaining to the use of `feof()` while his code should work (the logic is sound), it does break.

The following method (used the same way as his), should be a working drop-in replacement.

```
function retrieveText($file, $min, $max)
{
    $output = Array();

    $line = -1;
    $handle = fopen($file, 'r');
    while(!feof($handle)) {
        $line++;
        if(($line >= $min && $line <= $max)) {
            $output[] = fgets($handle);
        } elseif($line > $max) {
            break;
        } else {
            fgets($handle);
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
    return implode("\n", $output);
}
```

Please note, this uses a carriage return to separate each line `"\n"`, which you can alter to `"<br />"` or whatever you like depending on where you will display the result.

Comment: not a problem.  will still leave this here in case someone is interested in a slightly altered version.  :)

Comment: Good example with array :) +1. When you send a message use the '@ username` why but not enough messages in the inbox, thanks!